# Struts logic- want to prevent duplicate message in email confirmation

Tags: struts

I'm new to struts so bear with me please.
I want to display a promotional message in the order confirmation email jsp. I'm pulling this promo code from a field on a shopping cart form. It works fine except it duplicates the message for every orderline. How do I get it to print only once for a given promo code?

```
<logic:iterate id="orderLineItem name="order" property="orderLines" type"=com.corporation.ecom.OrderLine">
<logic:notEmpty name="orderLineItem" property="promotionCodes">
    <logic:iterate id="promo" name="ordeLineItem" property="promotionCodes">
       <logic:equal name="promo" value="ABC">
        <p>Message goes here...............
        </p>
       </logicEqual>
       <logic:equal name="promo" value="XYZ">
        <p>Message goes here...............
        </p>
       </logicEqual>
    </logic:iterate>
</logic:notEmpty>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: It duplicates which message? And ew; it'd be much cleaner (and easier to test) if this was done server-side.

Comment: It duplicates the message between the paragraph tags that is generated whenever promo code ABC or XYZ is entered in the form field. Messages are different for each code and the codes are tied to specific cart items. Right now it will print the message for each line rather than once for the entire order.

Comment: It's inside the `orderLines`' `<logic:iterate>`, so that's what I'd expect.

Comment: So I should iterate through promotionCodes first, then orderLines?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, I don't know what you're actually trying to do.

If, for example, the user enters a promo code, and it's a promo-code-per-order, but must match the promo code of a line item, then you're doing it wrong--you need to check the entered promo code against each item's promo code, and see if there's a match anywhere. If there is, then print the appropriate message.

Doing this in the JSP is a PITA: I'd do it as a JSP fragment or as a JSP-based custom tag. Ideally it'd be done on the server side, where it's far less bulky, and way easier to test. Where/how the promo message is stored also makes a difference.

Comment: It is one promo code per order matching a line item. I understand why you would want to handle this server side. In fact we are considering a code change whereby we can update messages through the database rather than hardcoding but we're not there yet. We usually store messages in a rules file and they are displayed as pop ups in the cart at checkout when the matching promo code is entered. I'll investigate your JSP suggestions, thanks for your help as I'm muddling my way through this.

Comment: @Scout Then you need to compare against the order's promo code (not reflected in your original fragment), AFAICT. Even if the promo message is hard-coded in the JSP, it'd still be cleaner to do this work on the server side and expose a flag/etc. then use a JSTL `<c:when>` instead of the S1 tags. When JSTL and S1 tag functionality overlaps, use JSTL.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm looking at the logic in the class files right now.